# Pull Image from docker registry using lambda function

Tags: docker, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, docker-registry

I want to pull the docker image from the docker registry and store the image as a tar file in s3 using the lambda function.

So can anybody help me how can I pull a docker image from a registry without using the docker daemon client?